# How to run Flutter driver tests remotely

Tags: flutter, ui-automation, bitrise, flutterdriver

We have Flutter driver tests running locally with a command like:

```
flutter drive --target=test_driver/app.dart --driver=test_driver/test/login_test.dart  --flavor dev --no-start-paused
```

And having an Android device plugged in to the computer.

Now we want to run these tests remotely. We are trying to figure out which devices in the cloud provider is the best for running flutter driver tests.

We tried following the guide on https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/integration-tests and run them on Firebase Testlab but we couldnt make it work, or it is not possible with Flutter driver tests.

Which devices in the cloud provider we should choose for running flutter driver tests? We have got Bitrise as CI solution.

Comment: I've made it work on Bitrise by running a manual script that boots up the iphone simulator. Try running `open -a Simulator.app` in a script step before your drive tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Android, you can use the `AVD Manager` step to create an Android emulator and add `Wait for Android emulator` step to wait for the emulator to finish the boot.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Adding an AVD Manager step works. But we would also like to give Firebase Testlab a try. Do you know it is possible to trigger Flutter driver tests against Firebase Testlab?